# apache server down after easyapache rebuild

Tags: php, apache-2.2, ssh

I have rebuilt my apache server (running CentOS using WHM) to update my apache feature using easyapache.

After the rebuild process which ended with build successful, my site become inaccessible with the error msg : cant connect to server.

I already restarted apache server and sql, and then rebuilt again but had the same result.

I already disabled the firewall due to rebuild process.

Here is the error log

```
[Fri Dec 23 00:17:40 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Dec 23 00:17:42 2011] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Fri Dec 23 00:17:42 2011] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/local/apache/bin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 23 00:17:42 2011] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Fri Dec 23 00:17:42 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 23 15:52:13 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Dec 23 15:52:15 2011] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Fri Dec 23 15:52:15 2011] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/local/apache/bin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 23 15:52:15 2011] [notice] ModSecurity for Apache/2.6.2 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Fri Dec 23 15:52:15 2011] [notice] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.4.5"; loaded version="1.4.5"
[Fri Dec 23 15:52:15 2011] [notice] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.12"; loaded version="8.12 2011-01-15"
[Fri Dec 23 15:52:15 2011] [notice] ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.1"
[Fri Dec 23 15:52:15 2011] [notice] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.7.8"
[Fri Dec 23 15:52:16 2011] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Fri Dec 23 15:52:16 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:38 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:40 2011] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:40 2011] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/local/apache/bin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:40 2011] [notice] ModSecurity for Apache/2.6.2 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:40 2011] [notice] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.4.5"; loaded version="1.4.5"
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:40 2011] [notice] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.12"; loaded version="8.12 2011-01-15"
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:40 2011] [notice] ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.1"
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:40 2011] [notice] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.7.8"
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:41 2011] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:41 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 PHP/5.2.17 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:46 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:48 2011] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:48 2011] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/local/apache/bin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:48 2011] [notice] ModSecurity for Apache/2.6.2 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:48 2011] [notice] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.4.5"; loaded version="1.4.5"
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:48 2011] [notice] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.12"; loaded version="8.12 2011-01-15"
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:48 2011] [notice] ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.1"
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:48 2011] [notice] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.7.8"
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:49 2011] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Fri Dec 23 15:53:49 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 PHP/5.2.17 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 23 16:01:21 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/server-status
[Fri Dec 23 16:01:39 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/server-status
[Fri Dec 23 16:10:46 2011] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Fri Dec 23 16:10:47 2011] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Fri Dec 23 16:10:47 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 PHP/5.2.17 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 23 16:46:59 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Dec 23 16:47:01 2011] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Fri Dec 23 16:47:01 2011] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/local/apache/bin/suexec)
[Fri Dec 23 16:47:01 2011] [notice] ModSecurity for Apache/2.6.2 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Fri Dec 23 16:47:01 2011] [notice] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.4.5"; loaded version="1.4.5"
[Fri Dec 23 16:47:01 2011] [notice] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.12"; loaded version="8.12 2011-01-15"
[Fri Dec 23 16:47:01 2011] [notice] ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.1"
[Fri Dec 23 16:47:01 2011] [notice] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.7.8"
[Fri Dec 23 16:47:02 2011] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Fri Dec 23 16:47:02 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 PHP/5.2.17 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: Have you checked apache is running? Do you get any error messages when you restart apache? Have you checked the apache error logs? ps this question might be more appropriate for ServerFault.

Comment: Apache is running, ive checked via Apache status. Restarting Apache also no error. Apache error logs just notice report. is it better to paste here the logs?

Comment: Do you have shell access? Have you checked netstat to see if apache is listening and on what IP/ports?

Comment: yes i accessed from Terminal SSH. How to check it, Im a newbie here. =)

Comment: If you run "netstat -antp | grep httpd" in your terminal (just the bit inside the quotes, not the quotes themselves) and post the output.

Comment: tcp        0      0 10.45.81.2:443              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1915/httpd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:443               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1915/httpd          
tcp        0      0 10.45.81.2:80               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1915/httpd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1915/httpd

Comment: is it means the http port 80 is open properly?

Comment: It looks like it's listening on 10.45.81.2 and the loopback IP. How are you connecting to the server, is it remote? Are you using the IP address or a hostname? Is that the right IP (10.45.81.2)? I tried connecting to http://10.45.81.2 and it times out for me too.

Comment: Do you have fullstatus enabled?
This line: [Fri Dec 23 16:01:21 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/server-status

Comment out the fullstatus info in the apache config and see what happens upon restart.

Answer (score 1):

The only errors in your log are this:

```
[Fri Dec 23 16:01:21 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/server-status
[Fri Dec 23 16:01:39 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/server-status
```

In your log, "Errors" will prevent Apache from running, while Notices should still be addressed for optimum performance, but will still allow Apache to run.

From the shell, try touching /usr/local/apache/htdocs/server-status:

```
touch /usr/local/apache/htdocs/server-status
```

And then chown that to the apache user (assuming the user "apache" runs the Apache processes, then run...)

```
chown apache.apache /usr/local/apache/htdocs/server-status
```